# Загружаются пустые файлы с FTP python-скриптом

Tags: python, ftp

Такая проблема... При загрузке файлов с FTP-сервера некоторые загружаются пустыми (не все). Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём может быть проблема?

Вот кусок кода...

```
ftp_host = ''
ftp_user = ''
ftp_password = ''
ftp_connect = FTP(ftp_host, ftp_user, ftp_password)
ftp_connect.cwd('IN')
file_names = ftp_connect.nlst()
for filename in file_names:
    host_file = os.path.join('c:/ftp_test/', filename)
    try:
        with open(host_file, 'wb') as local_file:
            print('Copy... ' + filename)
            ftp_connect.retrbinary('RETR ' + filename, local_file.write)
    except ftplib.error_perm:
        pass
```

Comment: Может дело в параметре maxblocksize метода retrbinary?

Answer (score 0):

`nlst` возвращает как имена файлов, так и директорий.
Вероятно пустые локальные файлы - это ftp директории. Те надо делать както так:

```
folders_and_files = ftp_connect.nlst()
file_names = [name for name in folders_and_files if (not ftp_connect.cwd(name))]
for filename in file_names:
    ...
```

А вообще ответ на ваш вопрос `except ftplib.error_perm`
Когда возникает эта ошибка, файл `open(host_file, 'wb')` уже создан, но тк из за ошибки ничего не скачалось, файл остался пустой.

Comment: 100 % на FTP в этой папке нет директорий. Я вручную сравниваю файлы - на FTP он, допустим, 410 килобайт, а локально - 0. Спасибо за информацию, приму к сведению.